# How to maintain original dashes in SVG after animating ?

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I have a SVG that i am trying to animate and i am using the following jQuery. What i really want to do is make an animation of the dotted line being drawn , while keeping the dots intact.

```
$(function () {

    $("#dotted-lines path").css({
        'fill': 'none'
    });

    var length;

    $("#dotted-lines path").each(function () {

        var $this = $(this);
        length = $this[0].getTotalLength();
        $this.attr('data-length', length).css({
            'stroke-dashoffset': length,
                'stroke-dasharray': length
        });

    });


    $("#dotted-lines path").each(function () {

        $(this).animate({
            'stroke-dashoffset': 0
        }, {

            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'linear',
            complete: function () {

            }
        });

    });

});
```

The above code can be seen in action **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/rr7fn41v/1/)** , Now the line gets drawn perfectly , just the way i wanted it to be animated, but unfortunatly the line is no longer dashed. so how do i maintain the original dashes ?

One more thing i tried was , on the below line:

```
$this.attr('data-length', length).css({'stroke-dashoffset': length, 'stroke-dasharray': length});
```

if i change it to:

```
        $this.attr('data-length', length).css({'stroke-dashoffset': length, 'stroke-dasharray': "5,3"});
```

I get the dashes but i don't get the drawing effect . so as i said , how do i maintain the original dashes ?

Comment: If your background is a solid color then you could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rr7fn41v/2/) where I've overlapped another path (cover) on top of the existing path and animated its offset. This produces an effect like the dots are being drawn. If that's useful for you then I'll add as answer (Note: I couldn't get rid of the outline artifiact which is showing along the path though.)

Comment: @Harry i was expecting you over here :D :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a linear-gradient to the path with: `stroke: url(#reveale);`
This is the the svg gradient that looks like this:

```
    <linearGradient id="reveale">
      <stop offset="0%" id="move-opacity" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="0%" id="last-opacity" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="black" />
    </linearGradient>
```

Using jquery i animate the offset with inside an interval.
There are two stop colors in the linearGradient, this is for creating a instant transition from solid to transparent color.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var offset = parseInt($('#move-opacity').attr("offset"));
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#move-opacity').attr("offset", offset + "%");
    if (offset < 100) {
      $('#last-opacity').attr("offset", (offset + 1) + "%");
    }
    offset++;
  }, 25);
});
```

```css
#dotted-lines {
  stroke: url(#reveale);
  fill: none;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-dasharray: 0.9795;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve" width="50%">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }
    .st1 {
      fill: #FFDE17;
    }
    .st2 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }
    .st3 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      stroke-dasharray: 0.9795, 0.9795;
    }
  </style>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="reveale">
      <stop offset="0%" id="move-opacity" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="0%" id="last-opacity" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="black" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path id="XMLID_9_" class="st0" d="M50,15.3H8.4c-2.8,0-5,2.3-5,5v58c0,2.8,2.3,5,5,5H50c2.8,0,5-2.3,5-5v-58
   C55,17.6,52.8,15.3,50,15.3z M14,19.4h28.1c0.9,0,1.6,0.7,1.6,1.6s-0.7,1.6-1.6,1.6H14c-0.9,0-1.6-0.7-1.6-1.6S13.1,19.4,14,19.4z
    M28.8,82.8c-1.6,0-3-1.3-3-3s1.3-3,3-3s3,1.3,3,3S30.4,82.8,28.8,82.8z M48.9,69.2c0,2.8-2.3,5-5,5H13.7c-2.8,0-5-2.3-5-5V32
   c0-2.8,2.3-5,5-5h30.3c2.8,0,5,2.3,5,5V69.2z" />
  <path id="XMLID_4_" class="st1" d="M23,48.8h10.2V45c0-1.4-0.5-2.6-1.5-3.6s-2.2-1.5-3.6-1.5c-1.4,0-2.6,0.5-3.6,1.5
   c-1,1-1.5,2.2-1.5,3.6V48.8L23,48.8z M39.5,50.7v11.4c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.3c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.6-1.3,0.6h-19c-0.5,0-1-0.2-1.3-0.6
   c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.8-0.6-1.3V50.7c0-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.3s0.8-0.6,1.3-0.6h0.6V45c0-2.4,0.9-4.5,2.6-6.3c1.7-1.7,3.8-2.6,6.3-2.6
   s4.5,0.9,6.3,2.6s2.6,3.8,2.6,6.3v3.8h0.6c0.5,0,1,0.2,1.3,0.6C39.3,49.7,39.5,50.1,39.5,50.7L39.5,50.7z" />
  <g id="dotted-lines">
    <g id="XMLID_20_">
      <path id="XMLID_22_" d="M59.2,58.4c3.1-4.6,15.5-20.1,37-15.4" />
    </g>
  </g>
  <polyline id="XMLID_3_" class="st2" points="97.3,40.8 99,44.2 96.3,46.4 " />
</svg>
```

Comment: If you want to know anything about the code then I'm here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/css-shapes-svg-and-designs

Comment: I believe the `stroke-miterlimit` property is used when two lines are intersecting .. any perticular reason you used it in the above example ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik nope i copied it from your code. I do not think it is needed anymore.